# How to write overloads that takes Func<T,Task<T2>> and Func<T,T2> without explicit cast

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.6.1

I have a method that has two overloads

```
void Foo(Func<T,T2> syncDelegate) {} //1
void Foo(Func<T,Task<T2>> asyncDelegate){} //2
```

Then I have a Bar method that is implemented like this

```
async Task<T2> Bar(T input)
{
// some await code here
}
```

The `Foo` is then called like this

```
Foo(Bar); //3
```

Due to the nature of async/await which unwraps the Task and makes my `Bar` is equivalent to

```
T2 Bar(T input)
```

To make it work, I have to explicitly cast `//3` like this

```
Foo((Func<T,Task<T2>>)Bar);
```

Is there any elegant way to avoid this explicit cast?

**UPDATE**
To clarify the purpose of Foo

Foo() is not a method that invokes delegates. It registers the delegate and the delegates will be invoked by a different mechanism.
The reason Foo() doesn't have type parameter is because the type parameter is declared at the class level.

Full mockup code can be found here https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6UCpi

Comment: Are both Foos async? Async methods should be postfixed with 'Async'.

Comment: @tymtam Foos are not async method. What it does is registering the delegate and the delegate will be invoked later by different mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a very elegant solution: named parameter.

Instead of calling

```
Foo(Bar);
```

I should call it with explicit named parameter which declared in the OP.

```
Foo(asyncDelegate: Bar);
```

This explicitly tells the compiler to use the async overload and avoid ambiguity without explicit casting.

View this for full snippet 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6UCpi

Comment: @ LXL could u give us the link for the source ? where you have find asyncdelegate ?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, look at the function signatures for the two Foo overloads in the original Question (above).  The two overloads have different parameter names, and apparently the type deduction takes that into account.

Comment: This solution [does not compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s2erV9) with the given example.

Comment: @JohnWu your version is different from mine. I defined type parameter on the class level https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6UCpi rather than method level. Therefore, the compiler is able to infer the T and T2

Comment: @DaveM if you don't have type parameters declared at class level. John Wu's example still work if you call Foo like this : `Foo<string,string>(asyncDelegate: Bar<string,string>);` where you tell the compiler the type for T and T2

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing is not about async/await but about methods with signatures that only differ by return type.

This can be demonstrated with this simple example:

```
static T2 Bar<T, T2>(T t)
{
    return default(T2);
}

static IList<T2> Bar<T, T2>(T t)
{
    return new List<T2>();
}
```

This code will result in *Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Bar' with the same parameter types* error

---

Here's a full snippet without any async/await:

```
    static T2 Foo<T, T2>(Func<T, T2> d1)
    {
        return d1(default(T));
    }
    static IList<T2> Foo<T, T2>(Func<T, IList<T2>> d2)
    {
        return d2(default(T));
    }

    static IList<T2> Bar<T, T2>(T t)
    {
        Console.Write($"Bar: {typeof(T).Name} -> {typeof(T2).Name}: '{default(T)}' -> '{default(T2)}'");
        return new List<T2>();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Foo<T, T2>(Func<T, T2>)' and 'Program.Foo<T, T2>(Func<T, IList<T2>>)'
        //Foo<string, int>(Bar<string, int>);


        //Prints: Bar: String -> Int32: '' -> '0'
        Foo<string, int>(d2: Bar<string, int>);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You have misunderstood my statement when I said "Due to the nature of async/await which unwraps the Task and makes my Bar is equivalent to T2 Bar(T input)". I don't have any method that is declared as T2 Bar(T input) in my code. Therefore, your example is totally diverged from the OP